# C++ add int to int array

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I add int to my int array. I do not want to set array size, I do not want to use external loop.

```
int myArray[] = {};
...
if (condition) 
{
    myArray.push(value);
}
```

Comment: You can't. The size of an array is fixed. Use an `std::vector` if you need a dynamic array.

Comment: @JonathanMee forget it, I'll delete my comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Leon suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6394138/leon) what you're looking for is [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and specifically its [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method.

You could use it as follows:

```
vector<int> myArray; // currently size 0

if(condition) {
    myArray.push_back(value); // now resized to 1;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can use an [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) to print a `vector`. For example:

```
copy(cbegin(myArray), cend(myArray), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "))
```

Comment: can I print that vector in one line? with for loop?

Comment: @TeodorKolev, if you insist on a single line : `for (int i : myArray) std::cout << i << ' ';` :)

Comment: @StoryTeller `ostream_iterator` is a better solution, and it fits on a single line ;)

Comment: @TeodorKolev You can do better than a `for`-loop. See my edit.

Comment: How is better than for loop?

Comment: @JonathanMee I got many errors... Should I add some includes or something?

Comment: @TeodorKolev It automates the iterator for you preventing mistakes. It's also clearer to the user what's happening.

Comment: @TeodorKolev You'll need, `#include <vector>` for the `vector`, `#include <algorithm>` for the `copy`, `#include <iterator>` for the `ostream_iterator`, and `#include <iostream>` for `cout`.

Comment: @JonathanMee A range based for loop automates the iterator protocol just as well. I don't buy that using an algorithm is more readable in this case. (Although I agree that one should prefer re-use of algorithms, this is going a bit too far IMHO)

Comment: @StoryTeller I can agree with that, though my personal preference is the `copy` statement, particularly to the multi-lined `for`-statement, or even worse the single line `for`-statement.

Comment: This copy(begin(resultArrary), end(resultArrary), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); do nothing

Comment: @JonathanMee, well, can't argue with preferences :)

Comment: @TeodorKolev That's because `resultArray` is empty.

Comment: But i push back it

Comment: @TeodorKolev, are you sure? Print the vectors `size()` first.

Comment: @TeodorKolev Use your debugger to look at the contents, or if you insist you can dump the size: `cout << size(resultArray) << endl`

Comment: @TeodorKolev Sorry, I'm using C++17 syntax, try: `cout << resultArray.size() << endl`

Comment: Size is ok, it sill did not printing anything

Comment: @TeodorKolev A size of 0 is not OK, it means that you have nothing to print. If your size is non-0 and you're not printing anything you're gonna need to show some code for me to help any further.

Comment: My size is 3, how it has to be, so it is ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128363/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-teodorkolev).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use push into an array. I would suggest you to use [lists](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) if you don't want to set any size.

Comment: list have sub-performance most of the time, except in a truly parallel setting. It's better to turn to `std::vector` by default.

Comment: Also you should prefer linking to cppreference.com over cplusplus.com (the latter one is occasionally inaccurate)